# How do I properly post a message to a simple Go Chatserver using REST API

Tags: go

I am currently building a simple chat server that supports posting messages through a REST API.

````
 example:
 ========

 ```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"user":"alex", "text":"this is a message"}' http://localhost:8081/message

 {
   "ok": true
 }
````

Right now, I'm just currently storing the messages in an array of messages. I'm pretty sure this is an inefficient way. So is there a simple, better way to get and store the messages using goroutines and channels that will make it thread-safe.

Here is what I currently have:

```
type Message struct {
    Text string
    User string
    Timestamp time.Time
}

var Messages = []Message{}


func messagePost(c http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var m Message
    err := decoder.Decode(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if m.Timestamp == (time.Time{}) {
        m.Timestamp = time.Now()
    }
    addUser(m.User)
    Messages = append(Messages, m)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be made thread safe using mutex, as @ThunderCat suggested but I think this does not add concurrency. If two or more requests are made simultaneously, one will have to wait for the other to complete first, slowing the server down.

**Adding Concurrency**: You make it faster and handle more concurrent request by using a queue (which is a Go channel) and a worker that listens on that channel - it'll be a simple implementation. Every time a message comes in through a Post request, you add to the queue (this is instantaneous and the HTTP response can be sent immediately). In another goroutine, you detect that a message has been added to the queue, you take it out append it to your Messages slice. While you're appending to Messages, the HTTP requests don't have to wait.

Note: You can make it even better by having multiple goroutines listen on the queue, but we can leave that for later.

This is how the code will somewhat look like:

```
type Message struct {
    Text string
    User string
    Timestamp time.Time
}

var Messages = []Message{}

// messageQueue is the queue that holds new messages until they are processed
var messageQueue chan Message

func init() { // need the init function to initialize the channel, and the listeners
    // initialize the queue, choosing the buffer size as 8 (number of messages the channel can hold at once)
    messageQueue = make(chan Message, 8) 

    // start a goroutine that listens on the queue/channel for new messages
    go listenForMessages()
}

func listenForMessages() {
    // whenever we detect a message in the queue, append it to Messages
    for m := range messageQueue {
        Messages = append(Messages, m)
    }
}

func messagePost(c http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var m Message
    err := decoder.Decode(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if m.Timestamp == (time.Time{}) {
        m.Timestamp = time.Now()
    }
    addUser(m.User)

    // add the message to the channel, it'll only wait if the channel is full
    messageQueue <- m 
}
```

**Storing Messages**: As other users have suggested, storing messages in memory may not be the right choice since the messages won't persist if the application is restarted. If you're working on a small, proof-of-concept type project and don't want to figure out the DB, you could save the Messages variable as a flat file on the server and then read from it every time the application starts (*Note: this should not be done on a production system, of course, for that you should set up a Database). But yeah, database should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use a mutex to make the program threadsafe.

```
var Messages = []Message{}
var messageMu sync.Mutex

...

messageMu.Lock()
Messages = append(Messages, m)
messageMu.Unlock()
```

There's no need to use channels and goroutines to make the program threadsafe.

A database is probably a better choice for storing messages than the in memory slice used in the question. Asking how to use a database to implement a chat program is too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Thank! I need to be able to store a list of messages with a timestamp, and then be able to access the 100 most recent messages using another REST API call. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexErling The *right* solution is a database. Persist the messages in a database, then have your handler for the other API call query the database sorting by timestamp LIMIT 100

Comment: A db is the way to go, the way the answer is written suggests otherwise is poi